# fail for read ethereum node base on leveldb.py

Tags: nodes, python, leveldb

I installed leveldb base on python3.6.but when I using leveldb.LevelDB import path for files to be read.
a error occered

"leveldb.LevelDBError: Corruption: 3 missing files; e.g.: D:/downloads_by_geth/chain/geth/nodes/000244.sst"

this is my code

```
db = leveldb.LevelDB('D:/downloads_by_geth/chain/geth/nodes')
```

this is folder "nodes"
[image]

I want know the file of ".sst" where from and how to read file of ".ldb"?

hope someone help me

Comment: I have the same probem, while `geth` is still running. try stopping geth and delete the `LOCK` file